# Testing pushViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, uinavigationcontroller, xctest

I´ve tried to setup a router for navigating to the right Viewcontroller. When I call this in the simulator, it does work fine.

BUT: When I try to test the outcome of this transition via the topViewController or presentedViewController property of my NavigationController, I always get every Viewcontroller but not the correct one.

My Method looks like the following:

```
func navigateToViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    self.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
}
```

As I said. It works perfectly fine in the Simulator but I´d like to test it. Every time I call this the ViewController is correctly set. But the result of the Test is a completely different Controller.

When I assert that the topViewController or presentedViewController should be a HomeViewController, I always get a different ViewController as result.

```
XCTAssertTrue(self.sut.topViewController is HomeViewController,
                   "The TopViewController should be set to the HomeViewController but instead: \(self.sut.topViewController)")
```

How could that be and how can I solve this?

Comment: Do you want a unit test, or a UI test?

Comment: It should be a unit test for my router. So that everything is correct including the presented ViewController.

Comment: It looks like your class is a subclass or extension of NavigationController. Could you share a little more of its interface?

Comment: Nope. The Instance of the Controller is the same. That´s why I don´t understand why it´s not working. In the NavigationViewController is nothing more than a switch based on a String to prepare the ViewController which will be passed to the "navigateToViewController" method.

Comment: Here I got a Sample Project with just the parts where the Problem occurs. Hope someone can help me about this Issue. https://github.com/Evil-Me/SegueUnitTestApp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Updated answer:*

Use https://github.com/jonreid/ViewControllerPresentationSpy

*Original answer:*

There doesn't seem to be a good way to unit test the *effects* of calling `performSegue`. What we can do instead is *record* how it was called. In the test code, add this:

```
fileprivate var performSegueIdentifiers: [String] = []

extension ViewController {
    override open func performSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) {
        performSegueIdentifiers.append(identifier)
     }
}
```

This changes ViewController's `performSegue`. Instead of actually performing the segue, we append the identifier to `performSegueIdentifiers`. Since this is file scoped, we need to be careful not to let it "bleed" into other tests. So reset it in `setUp`:

```
    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        performSegueIdentifiers = []
        // other set-up
    }
```

Now your tests can invoke test the contents of this array to determine:

- The number of times `performSegue` was called
- What segue identifiers were passed to it

We can trust that the actual `performSegue` works. All we need to test is that the production code called it correctly.

Comment: Thanks Jon for your response. I'll try this directly tomorrow morning. Sounds good so far. Many many thanks for your help. I appreciate this.

Comment: Jon you are my hero. It worked like a charm. I now can see what segue was performed and can check this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

try this code, it will help you get the class name of each view controller in the navigation controller's view controllers stack

```
for VC in (self.navigationController?.viewControllers)! {
            print(VC.classForCoder)
        }
```

because I'm not sure what else you have in your code that have possibly added some view controllers to your navigation controller's view controllers stack

Comment: I Did this and the Controller is not showing up in there.